# How to change the font of polari IRC chat client?

Tags: gnome

Is it possible to change the default font of the polari IRC chat client? I would like to change it to DejaVu Sans Mono.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be using the  GTK's fonts. You can't customize it in Polari. My GTK Theme was causing the "issue".